# SQL - Operator IN with operator WITH AS

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

***Using postgres***

The following SQL creates TestsTodo, having all the informations about a table tests.
It also have a TestsTodoIds, having only the ids of TestsTodo

Then, i want to update all the rows of a table "test_results", with all the ids in TestsTodoIds. I can do it by setting `"WHERE test_id IN (select id from TestsTodo)"` But i cant do it with `"WHERE test_id IN TestsTodoIds"`, which is basically the same, i don't understand why.

```
WITH 
    TestsTodo AS
    (
        -- Selecting from table tests
        
    ), 
    TestsTodoIds AS 
    ( 
        SELECT id FROM TestsTodo -- This returns all the. ids from TestsTodo
    )
    
    --UPDATE test_results 
    --SET status = 'FOUND_IN_DB' 
    --WHERE test_id IN (SELECT id FROM TestsTodo) 
    --RETURNING *  
    -- This works
    
    UPDATE test_results
    SET status = 'FOUND_IN_DB'
    WHERE test_id IN TestsTodoIds
    RETURNING * -- This does not
```

**Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TestsTodoIds"
LINE 31:  WHERE test_id IN TestsTodoId**s
^

Comment: `IN` takes a list of values, either hardcoded or via a `subquery` that returns a list of values. You're giving it a derived table

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN manual page references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CTE called `TestsTodoIds` is a virtual table with one column. It isn't a set of values, and IN needs a set of values. You could use

```
WHERE test_id IN (SELECT id FROM TestsTodoIds)
```

and your query would function correctly.

That CTE is, in my opinion, unnecessary. The WHERE clause I suggested will perform exactly the same as

```
WHERE test_id IN (SELECT id FROM TestsTodo)
```

and you'll have less complexity to cope with when reading and reasoning about the query.